# MySQL sum elements of other table

Tags: mysql

I've got following tables:

Products:

```
id | price
```

Invoice:

```
id | product_id | amount | total
```

Column **total** should contain price of products multiplied by their amount. 
For example:

Products:

```
1 | 3.00
```

Invoice:

```
1 | 1 | 5 | 15.00
```

I was trying to fill total column by typing:

```
SELECT product_id, amount, (amount * SELECT price from products WHERE id=product_id) as 'total' FROM invoice;
```

It doesn't work. My question is, how to add value of products to column total?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using inner query (you just had misplaced bracket).

`SELECT product_id, amount, amount * (SELECT price from products WHERE id=product_id) as 'total' FROM invoice;`

Or using JOIN

`SELECT product_id, amount, amount*price as 'total' from invoice inner join products on invoice.product_id=products.id`

To update the total column in invoice table:

`update invoice set total=amount*(select price from products where id=product_id);`

Answer (score 0):

You simply need `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT *, (Products.price * amount) as total
FROM Invoice INNER JOIN Products
ON Invoice.id = Products.id
```